# Is OR and ELSE similar in list comprehension statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, generator-expression

Kindly help me understand why this works. The code below lists duplicates in an iterable. However, the use of the **or** operator behaves like the else in an if..else statement..

```
j = set()
my_list = [1, 2, 3 ,3 , 3 ,4, 4]
j_add = j.add
twice = set(x for x in my_list if x in j or j_add(x))
print list(twice)
```

Would expect the line to be:

```
 twice = set(x for x in my_list if x in j else j_add(x))
```

Thought or returns a boolean not a value

Comment: Technically speaking, you don't have a list comprehension, you have a generator expression.

Comment: No, the `or` is not an `else` statement. It is part of the test. You can use the same boolean expression in any `if` or `while` statement. `or` **short-circuits**, it'll not execute the right-hand expression if the left-hand expression produced a true value.

Comment: Thanks..the objective is not to remove duplicates, but to capture them. The above code will return [3, 4] when executed.

Comment: Thanks..got your second comment

Comment: Right, if you want to capture items that appear more than once, use a `Counter()` and filter on the resulting counts. That leads to far cleaner code.

Comment: I normally put it the other way around. Try this: twice = set(x if x in j else j_add(x) for x in my_list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `or` operator returns the last evaluated argument, which may or may not be a Boolean.

This behavior is explained in the [Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=operator#boolean-operations):

> Note that neither `and` nor `or` restrict the value and type they return to `False` and `True`, but rather return the last evaluated argument. This is sometimes useful, e.g., if `s` is a string that should be replaced by a default value if it is empty, the expression `s or 'foo'` yields the desired value.

Of course, it helps to remember what is interpreted as false and what is interpreted as true:

> [T]he following values are interpreted as false: `False`, `None`, numeric zero of all types, and empty strings and containers (including strings, tuples, lists, dictionaries, sets and frozensets). All other values are interpreted as true.

So in the expression:

```
A = B or C
```

As @MartijnPieters points out in a comment, an `or` expression short-circuits. If the first argument (`B` in this case) is interpreted as true, the entire expression must be true so the second argument (`C`) is never evaluated. Therefore the first argument (`B`) is "the last evaluated argument" and is what is returned. However, if the first argument (`B`) is interpreted as false, the second argument (`C`) must still be evaluated to determined the truthiness of the expression (no short-circuit takes place). In that case, "the last evaluated argument" is the second argument (`C`), which is returned regardless of whether the expression evaluates true or false.

It *effectively* accomplishes the same as the [Conditional Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html?highlight=operator#conditional-expressions):

```
A = B if B else C
```

However, Conditional Expressions were only added to Python in version 2.5, while the Boolean Operator behavior has existed from the beginning (or at least for a very long time). Most seasoned Python programmers will easily recognize and are in the habit of using `A = B or C`. Conditional Expressions are commonly reserved for more complex conditions that won't work with a simple `or` (for example in `A = B if X else C` the condition is not based on the truthiness of `B` but `X`, which could be anything from a simple value to a complex expression).

However, you need to be careful because, as JaredGoguen points out in his answer, changing the `or` to an `else` in the OP's sample actually changes the behavior of the code. That code was written to depend on this specific behavior of the `or` operator. You can't just replace any use of `or` for assignment with a Conditional Expression. Additional refactoring may be needed as well.

Answer (score 1):

I might make a value judgment here and say that this is not good code because it is using the short-circuiting behavior of `or` to produce a side-effect.

Consider the given conditional: `if x in j or j_add(x)`.

When `x in j`, the `or` short-circuits, skips the `j_add(x)` part of the conditional, and evaluates as `True`.

When `x not in j`, the statement `j_add(x)` is checked for its truthiness. This method returns `None`, which is falsy, and so `or` evaluate as `False`.

So, the entire conditional will evaluate the same as `x in j`. However `j_add(x)` has the side-effect of adding `x` to `j`! This side-effect is being exploited in order to record the unique members `my_list` in a quick-and-dirty comprehension.

Changing the `or` to an `else` would still construct `j` as desired, but it would inappropriately add `None`, the return value of `j_add(x)`, to `twice`.